Why do I get "out of memory" when running apt-get in docker build
I'm trying to install ca-certificates in my docker container and really having no luck.
I can apt-get update, and I can install some other packages, but not curl or ca-certificates. Further, if I run the ubuntu base container and exec -it into it, I can apt-get install ca-certificates there.
Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV http_proxy=http://my_proxy_that_probably_doesnt_matter

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates

Bash:
docker build .
or
docker build -m 4g .
And here is the log for this step:
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates:                                                                                 
0.275 Reading package lists...                                                                                                   
1.169 Building dependency tree...
1.346 Reading state information...
1.600 The following additional packages will be installed:
1.600   openssl
1.628 The following NEW packages will be installed:
1.630   ca-certificates openssl
1.733 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1.733 Need to get 1161 kB of archives.
1.733 After this operation, 2324 kB of additional disk space will be used.
1.733 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 openssl amd64 3.0.13-0ubuntu3 [1002 kB]
1.753 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20240203 [159 kB]
1.909 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
1.909 debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
1.909 debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
1.910 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
1.910 debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC entries checked: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.38.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.38 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38 /usr/share/perl/5.38 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 8, <STDIN> line 2.)
1.910 debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
1.917 dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
1.963 Fetched 1161 kB in 0s (10.4 MB/s)
1.978 Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
(Reading database ... 4937 files and directories currently installed.)
1.986 Preparing to unpack .../openssl_3.0.13-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
1.987 Unpacking openssl (3.0.13-0ubuntu3) ...
2.032 Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
2.033 Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20240203_all.deb ...
2.034 Unpacking ca-certificates (20240203) ...
2.089 Setting up openssl (3.0.13-0ubuntu3) ...
2.093 Setting up ca-certificates (20240203) ...
2.179 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
2.179 debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
2.179 debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2.179 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
2.179 debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC entries checked: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.38.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.38 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38 /usr/share/perl/5.38 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 8.)
2.179 debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
2.806 Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
3.577 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.578 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.579 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.580 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.581 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.582 out of memory
3.583 out of memory
3.583 out of memory
3.583 out of memory
3.583 out of memory
3.583 out of memory
3.584 out of memory
3.584 out of memory
3.584 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.585 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.586 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.587 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.588 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.589 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.590 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.591 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.592 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.593 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.594 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.595 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.596 out of memory
3.610 dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
3.610  installed ca-certificates package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 146
3.613 Errors were encountered while processing:
3.613  ca-certificates
3.630 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     RUN apt-get update
   6 |     RUN apt-get install -y dialog apt-utils gnupg lsb-release
   7 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y ca-certificates" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

EDIT: setting the memory to something silly high like 4g does not help

@whoever judges questions for relevancy. Please let me know what information in the post to troubleshoot this. I'm completely stumped about what could be eating memory in a really simple container.

Some time this error occur when the build exceeds the limitation for docker containers. You can specify a new limit with -m option when you attempt a build.
docker build -f Dockerfile -m 4g .

